# How to add a blog section to a website without using wordpress? Is there a way to integrate Headless CMS?

Tags: web, content-management-system, blogs, strapi, headless-cms

I'm trying to figure out how to add a blog section to my brother's website and I don't want to write everything from scratch. He suggested to use Headless CMS like Strapi, but I can't find anywhere how to incorporate it on the website. Will very much appreciate some feedback from you! Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "blog section"?  New Pages or block(widgets) to integrate into current pages/posts?

Comment: @fiblan I mean a block where the posts are. Not a new page